# How to fix Django Duplicate key form from being valid and saved?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This is my `views.py` file and Im getting this message

```
DETAIL:  Key (member_id, match_id)=(4, 20) already exists.
```

However is see that Valid is printing so its obvious the `is_valid()` method doesnt catch this duplicate key.

```
def update_batter_form(request, match_id, batting_id):
    """Edit existing batter form view."""

    obj = Batting.objects.get(pk=batting_id)
    form = BattingForm(instance=obj)
    batting_list_bn = Batting.objects.order_by('batter_number') \
        .filter(match_id=match_id)
    match = Match.objects.get(pk=match_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Printing POST")
        form = BattingForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        print(obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Valid")
            form.save()
            return redirect('/club/match/'+match_id+'/batter/'+batting_id)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return redirect('/club/match/' + match_id + '/batter/' + batting_id)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'batting_list_bn': batting_list_bn,
        'match': match
    }

    return render(request, 'club/batter_update.html', context)
```

EDIT Batting model and form

```
class Batting(models.Model):
    """Batting performances within a match."""

    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    batter_number = models.IntegerField(
        blank=False, default=1, validators=[MaxValueValidator(11), MinValueValidator(1)]
    )
    fours = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True, null=True, default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(300), MinValueValidator(0)]
    )
    sixes = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True, null=True, default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(300), MinValueValidator(0)]
    )
    runs = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True, null=True, default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000), MinValueValidator(0)]
    )
    mode_of_dismissal = models.ForeignKey(Wicket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    out_by = models.ForeignKey(
        OppositionNames, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', blank=True, null=True
    )
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""

        unique_together = (("batter_number", "match",), ("member", "match",),)

    def __str__(self):
        return str('{0} {1} scored {2} runs'
                   .format(self.member, self.match.date, self.runs)
                   )
```

```
class BattingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Batting
        exclude = ('match',)
```

How is it I catch this issue?

Comment: where is member_id coming from? do you have member_id and match_id as unique together constraint in models

Comment: Please add your form `BattingForm` and your model `Batting` to the question. Also show the url pattern for this url `'/club/match/'+match_id+'/batter/'+batting_id` of yours.

Comment: Batting form is just generic all fields and ive added the batting model @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: I haven’t added any cleans @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: @Joelad just add the form to the question. You say that `is_valid` is not checking the unique constraints right? That means it is a problem with the form...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat there ya go. Nothing special

Comment: Yeah @Neeraj Ive added my batting model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form you have set `exclude` as follows: `exclude = ('match',)`. When we exclude a field from the form, the form also excludes it from the validation it performs, which is only logical in the case that the form may be used to create this model's instances.

Since you need the field `match` to be part of the validation the best method is to simply make `match` a disabled and hidden field on the form. This will cause the field to be rendered with the disabled and hidden attributes. Also even if the user tampers with the field it will be ignored in favor of the initial value of the field:

```py
class BattingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    match = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Match.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
        disabled=True
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Batting
        fields = '__all__'
```